# PowerDNS/GeoIP geoblock

Tags: dns-hosting, powerdns, powerdns-recursor

I'm setting up two (master-slave) authoritative domain servers using PowerDNS with GeoIP backend.

The idea is to direct North America and Europe visitors to the server closest to them and block/drop traffic from all other continents.

Please find my geoip-zone.yml below. What should I set for the non-NA and non-EU zones? I believe this can be accomplished with Lua Records but I couldn't sort out how to set it up from the available documentation.

Thanks in advance for pointing out any errors as well.

```
domains:
- domain: domain.com
  ttl: 30
  records:
    domain.com:
      - soa: ns1.domain.com admin.domain.com 2021020101 7200 3600 1209600 3600
      - ns: ns1.domain.com
      - ns: ns2.domain.com
      - a: XXX.XX.XX.XX

    ns1.domain.com:
      - a: XXX.XX.XX.XX
    ns2.domain.com:
      - a: YY.Y.Y.Y

    na.domain.com:              
      - a: XXX.XX.XX.XX
    eu.domain.com:        
      - a: YY.Y.Y.Y
    af.domain.com:
    an.domain.com:
    as.domain.com:
    oc.domain.com:
    sa.domain.com:
  services:
    www.domain.com: '%cn.domain.com'
```